# Nomin and Spring Boot application: recursive mapping rule a = b causes infinite loop

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-boot-devtools, bootrun, nomin

As I had already few issues with combination Nomin, Eclipse and Groovy (see [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234524/nomin-automap-causes-infinite-loop) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329112/running-nomin-mapper-under-eclipse-cause-nominexception-resource-not-found)), I am again struggling with it.

My application works with JUnit Tests, both in Console via Gradle and Eclipse. But now it doesn't want to work when executing SpringBoot-Main class. Either in Eclipse nor with `gradle bootRun` on Console or Eclipse Gradle Task => Same Exception

```
@SpringBootApplication
class CcmApplication {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def ctx = SpringApplication.run CcmApplication, args
        def scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        print 'Press <Return> to quit program'
        scanner.nextLine()
        scanner.close()
        ctx.close()
    }
}
```

**Transformator Class:**

```
class CoinMarketCapTransformer {
    def resource = ClassPathResource.newInstance("coinmarketcap2coin.groovymapper")
    println resource.isFile() // Prints true
    println resource.isReadable() // Prints true
    Nomin nomin = Nomin.newInstance(resource.filename)

    CoinOnMarketPlace transform(Coin coin, @Header(name="marketName", required=true) String marketName) {
        MarketPlace marketPlace = MarketPlace.newInstance(name: marketName)
        CoinOnMarketPlace comp = nomin.map(coin, CoinOnMarketPlace)
        comp.setMarketPlace(marketPlace)
        comp
    }

    Coin transform(CoinOnMarketPlace comp) {
        nomin.map(comp, Coin.class)
    } 
}
```

**coinmarketcap2coin.groovymapper**
Why I named it `.groovymapper` please see in the link above. Its location is `src/main/resources`

```
import net.hemisoft.ccm.domain.CoinOnMarketPlace
import net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.Coin

mappingFor a: CoinOnMarketPlace, b: Coin
introspector exploding 
automap()

a.coin.coinId       =       b.coinId
a.coin.name         =       b.name
a.coin.symbol       =       b.symbol

a.lastUpdate        =       b.lastUpdateEpoch
convert to_a: { lastUpdateEpoch -> DateUtils.convertEpochMillis(lastUpdateEpoch) }
convert to_b: { lastUpdate -> DateUtils.convertLocalDateTime(lastUpdate) }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
2018-01-21 17:18:23.288 ERROR 16872 --- [sk-scheduler-10] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.nomin.core.NominException: org.nomin.Mapping: Recursive mapping rule a = b causes infinite loop!, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.Coin(bitcoin, Bitcoin, BTC, 1, 11524.4, 1.0, 9.96663E9, 1.93806837423E11, 1.6817087E7, 1.6817087E7, 2.1E7, -3.42, -10.21, -15.21, 1516551267), headers={sequenceNumber=1, Server=cloudflare, sequenceSize=100, Connection=keep-alive, http_statusCode=200, Date=1516551503000, marketName=coinMarketCap, Set-Cookie=__cfduid=dba860f31637c55e679ebf89660fcc7701516551503; expires=Mon, 21-Jan-19 16:18:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.coinmarketcap.com; HttpOnly; Secure, correlationId=dd703a62-f9b4-4838-ddfe-d5f272ce894a, id=c0ce3ae4-f478-c8c4-7901-dbf0061da1e2, Content-Length=54264, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1516551503272}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.Coin(bitcoin, Bitcoin, BTC, 1, 11524.4, 1.0, 9.96663E9, 1.93806837423E11, 1.6817087E7, 1.6817087E7, 2.1E7, -3.42, -10.21, -15.21, 1516551267), headers={sequenceNumber=1, Server=cloudflare, sequenceSize=100, Connection=keep-alive, http_statusCode=200, Date=1516551503000, marketName=coinMarketCap, Set-Cookie=__cfduid=dba860f31637c55e679ebf89660fcc7701516551503; expires=Mon, 21-Jan-19 16:18:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.coinmarketcap.com; HttpOnly; Secure, correlationId=dd703a62-f9b4-4838-ddfe-d5f272ce894a, id=c0ce3ae4-f478-c8c4-7901-dbf0061da1e2, Content-Length=54264, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1516551503272}]
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:238)
at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel.send(MessageChannel.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.lambda$configureChain$0(MessageHandlerChain.java:124)
at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel.send(MessageChannel.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:418)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:219)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:379)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:373)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.nomin.core.NominException: org.nomin.Mapping: Recursive mapping rule a = b causes infinite loop!, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.Coin(bitcoin, Bitcoin, BTC, 1, 11524.4, 1.0, 9.96663E9, 1.93806837423E11, 1.6817087E7, 1.6817087E7, 2.1E7, -3.42, -10.21, -15.21, 1516551267), headers={sequenceNumber=1, Server=cloudflare, sequenceSize=100, Connection=keep-alive, http_statusCode=200, Date=1516551503000, marketName=coinMarketCap, Set-Cookie=__cfduid=dba860f31637c55e679ebf89660fcc7701516551503; expires=Mon, 21-Jan-19 16:18:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.coinmarketcap.com; HttpOnly; Secure, correlationId=dd703a62-f9b4-4838-ddfe-d5f272ce894a, id=c0ce3ae4-f478-c8c4-7901-dbf0061da1e2, Content-Length=54264, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1516551503272}]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:107)
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90)
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
... 84 more
Caused by: org.nomin.core.NominException: org.nomin.Mapping: Recursive mapping rule a = b causes infinite loop!
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
at org.nomin.core.MappingEntry.validate(MappingEntry.groovy:64)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at org.nomin.core.MappingEntry.parse(MappingEntry.groovy:56)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1224)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1033)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1010)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:993)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodNSafe(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:176)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodNSpreadSafe(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:183)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0SpreadSafe(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
at org.nomin.Mapping.parse(Mapping.groovy:44)
at org.nomin.core.Nomin.findApplicable(Nomin.java:228)
at org.nomin.core.Nomin.findCachedApplicable(Nomin.java:211)
at org.nomin.core.Nomin.map(Nomin.java:201)
at org.nomin.core.Nomin.map(Nomin.java:159)
at org.nomin.core.Nomin.map(Nomin.java:156)
at org.nomin.NominMapper$map.call(Unknown Source)
at net.hemisoft.ccm.repository.CoinMarketCapTransformer.transform(CoinMarketCapTransformer.groovy:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1039)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:608)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:504)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:313)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:104)
... 86 more
```

**UPDATE:**

The following CodeSnippet from `Nomin.class` works as expected when running under Test. When running via bootRun the else if on line 220 is false, what should be true.

[image]

On line 220 we have `pm.sideB.isAssignableFrom(key.source)` what should result to `true`, because `pm.sideB` is type of `Coin`, and `key.source` is type of `Coin` (see Screenshots).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `spring-boot-devtools` runtime dependency. When you run your application with a debugger you will find out that classes **`net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.Coin`** and **`net.hemisoft.ccm.domain.CoinOnMarketPlace`** are loaded twice using two different classloaders:

- `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`
- `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader`

[image]

This is why following part of code evaluates to `false`:

```
else if (pm.sideB.isAssignableFrom(key.source) && pm.sideA.isAssignableFrom(key.target)) result.add(new MappingWithDirection(pm, false));
```

Even though `key.source` and `pm.sideB` seems to be the "same" classes, they are not equal because they are being managed by two different classloaders. Classes with the same canonical name are only equal inside the same classloader. And this is why your unit test works like a charm - there is no spring boot devtools involved and if you go with debugger to `Nomin.java:(line 220)` while running unit test, you will see that `key.source` and `pm.sideB` hold a reference to the same class inside one classloader so this expression evaluates to `true` and the mapping you defined is being used. Otherwise [nomin](/questions/tagged/nomin) tries to generate mapping automatically (it can be disabled with `Nomin.disableAutoMapping()`) and in this case, it uses default introspector - `ReflectionIntrospector`. This one causes issues with Groovy classes as we already figured out in one of your previous SO questions.

#### Solution

Disable `spring-boot-devtools` or disable restarts or at least try to exclude your domain classes from restarting application. You can check [Spring Boot Devtools docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) to see how to do it. I would just get rid of it - as you can see it makes your application running differently in your dev environment, so you can never be sure how it behaves when running live.

Comment: Hey Szymon, thank you very much for this awesome explanation. I was not aware about that classloader issue when using devtools. Currently I decided not using it, because it is currently not that important to me. Otherwise I will check out the documentation about it. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @MichaelHegner I'm glad I could help you :) Good luck and happy hacking!